# Feeling of lacking knowledge of IT world

Tags: computer-science

I have the feeling I have a serious lack of knowledge of the IT world, software used, libraries, and so on. I want to know if this is normal or I should really start learning more.

A little background about myself: I just graduated University in Computer Science, and studied Machine Learning, Computer Vision, AI and the like in the last year. I have studied C, C++, Python, OpenGL, Java, JavaScript, algorithms, data structures, and all what is expected from a Bachelor in Computer Science.

Whenever I read the requirements for job positions, tasks for freelancers, or challenges (such as Hackatons), there are always libraries, APIs, languages or the like I don't know and have never seen before.

For example, the following, required for different jobs, I have never seen before:

- SOAP
- Swagger
- Kafka
- SCSS
- ReactJS
- Okta SSO

And the list goes on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a personal development question rather than a programming one.

Comment: I understand. Where should I post this question better? Thank you.

Comment: This is normal. There is no end of libraries and frameworks and apis and tools. Decide what kind of work you want to do and that will narrow down which of these things you need to learn about. If you stay specialized in machine learning it's likely you are fine ignoring all the listed things without much concern, except kafka might be good to know.